# How can we use our folder as a subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Hi are there ways to make the subfolder type like these in a url.http://subfolder.domain.com

http://domain.com/subfolder
http://subfolder.domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible with `.htaccess` alone, you need to fiddle with your web server's config.

Comment: Actually, it's very much possible, although it *is* recommended to use the server's config.